# How can I remove the line between the JTextPane and the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextpane

I'm creating a text editor as my exam work and I have a main `JPanel` which all the Swing components are on. At the top I have a `JMenuBar` and in the center a `JTextPane` and at both sides I have panels that display images. The problem I have is that between the left side of the text pane and my right panel there is a weird line and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I have tried `setBorderPainted` to false on both my text pane and panel but that didn't work. In the first image there is a weird line between the text pane right side and the rights sides panel but not to the left panel.

[weird line between jtextpane and jpanel - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovvSp.png)

[no line - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mINmT.png)

The right side should look like the left side as shown in the second image.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of full window.

Comment: Do you have a border set?

Comment: and possibly some code.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say it's the border of the `JScrollPane`. In future, rather then screen shots, provide a [mcve]

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (But I suspect @MadProgrammer is correct, before even looking at the screenshots.)

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer was correct when I added the jtextpane to the panel without the jscrollpane the line disappeard.

When I typed in jscrollpane.setBorder(null); the line disappeard.

Here is a screenshot of the application.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnXrR.jpg "fullscreen"